# Prevent Selected Terms Rising to the Top

Tags: terms, user-interface, admin-ui

When you're editing a post and select a child category or term, and update, the selected terms appear at the top ( leading to potentially confusing situations where 'foo' 'foo' and 'foo' are selected each with different parents and no way to tell them apart ).

How do I prevent this behaviour? Either by showing the parent terms to give context, or stopping them being moved to the top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bugs me too. It is very confusing, so I thought I'd look into it.

That meta box is created in ["wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php" on line ~399](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L399). It uses [`wp_terms_checklist`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_terms_checklist). The problem codes seems to be this (it is one in source):

```
<?php wp_terms_checklist(
    $post->ID, array( 
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 
        'popular_cats' => $popular_ids 
) ) ?>
```

That leaves a couple of options that I can think of.

You could use Javascript to reorder the list. You can't remove the oddball categories because they won't be available in the list. But I doubt that would be either quick or easy.

Or, you can remove the default box with [`remove_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) and add back a near clone with [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) altering the line above to be:

```
<?php wp_terms_checklist(
    $post->ID, 
    array( 
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'popular_cats' => $popular_ids 
        'check_ontop' => false 
) ) ?>
```

The `checked_ontop` part is the key. Removing and adding a metabox seems a long way to go to add those few characters and I sort-of hate to do it because it is pretty close to a core hack (but isn't :) ), though changes to the core could mean a need to rewrite that function. I don't think there is any other real option though.

**EDIT:** OK. I originally thought that there was no hook that would help with this but there is one. All you need is:

```
function tst($args) {
    $args['checked_ontop'] = false;
    return $args;
}
add_filter('wp_terms_checklist_args','tst');
```

That is going to alter things globally so it may be necessary to alter that so that it only runs on particular pages.

Thanks to [Tom J Nowell](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/736/tom-j-nowell). Sometimes it is good to be wrong.

Comment: +1. Bugs me as well. Agree with you that your solution feels pretty hacky, but don't see any better options either.

Comment: Ah but that's not entirely true, the array passed into the function isn't passed into a filter, but thats because the first thing wp_terms_checklist does is pass it into a filter

Comment: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L99

Comment: Ah... completely missed that! A comment to another function confused me. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I even looked at that source file. I just missed it 0_o

Comment: Looks good, let me test it out

Comment: I would very much like to add the word "nested" this page. I searched far and wide for this solution, and I think having a phrase like "nested taxonomies" or "nested taxonomy checkboxes" or "nested hierarchical checkboxes" would help a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but if *you* know, looking at the initial hierarchy, which subcategories are appropriate, then you could use a plugin like [Parent Category Toggler](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/parent-category-toggler/) to auto-select the parent when you select the sub.

Comment: That would ~semi-solve the problem by applying all the terms ancestors to the post, but it doesn't prevent the behaviour, and doing that has other implications ( you dont need to check the parents for the post to appear in the parent terms anyway). It's also an extra step, any solution should be automated/transparent/effortless

Comment: True. Perhaps this is closer to what you need? [Category Checklist Tree](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-checklist-tree/)

Comment: Oddly enough it uses the same fix that is used in @s_ha_dum answer